# align text center with android

Tags: java, android, xml, text, center

I know it sounds easy.  I need to put a text in center, but when the text is too long it needs to go below, but still align in the center of my xml.

Here's my code :

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/showdescriptioncontenttitle"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
>
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/showdescriptiontitle"
        android:text="Title"
        android:textSize="35dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

I put paddingTop and Bottom because I need some space.
PS: My code is bigger; it's in a RelativeLayout.

Comment: Here you didn't use any text style

Answer (score 437, accepted):

Set also `android:gravity` parameter in `TextView` to `center`.

For testing the effects of different layout parameters I recommend to use different background color for every element, so you can see how your layout changes with parameters like gravity, layout_gravity or others.

Comment: Thank you, it worked, just need some time to valid your answer !

Comment: Yes, that's true. But I think only if the TextView has more than one line. Because with only 1 not full line of text, the TextView wont fill the layout horizontally

Comment: You can avoid this by setting TextView's android:layout_width="fill_parent"

Comment: Not to be confused with `android:layout_gravity`. Doh! :)

Answer (score 33):

use this way

```
txt.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
```

Answer (score 26):

use this way in xml

```
   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/myText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Time is precious, so love now."
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        />
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use the following:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/showdescriptioncontenttitle"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp">

 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Your text"
        android:typeface="serif" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The layout needs to be relative for the "center" property to be used.

Answer (score 5):

Adding `android:gravity="center"` in your TextView will do the trick (be the parent layout is `Relative/Linear`)!

Also, you should avoid using dp for font size. Use sp instead.

Answer (score 5):

Just add these 2 lines;

```
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:textAlignment="center"
```

Answer (score 3):

add layout_gravity and gravity with center value on TextView

```
<TextView
    android:text="welcome text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    />
```

Answer (score 1):

```
android:layout_gravity="center"
```

or

```
android:gravity="center"
```

both works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Or check this out this will help align all the elements at once.

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/showdescriptioncontenttitle"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
>
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/showdescriptiontitle"
        android:text="Title"
        android:textSize="35dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the alignment from the mainActivity.java file, then use the gravity. For example:

```
chatMsg.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
```

chatMsg is my textView. I wanted the text to be right aligned and this code worked well.

Answer (score 0):

you can easily done this by adding these lines

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:textAlignment="center"
```